# How can I automate creation of new environments for different customers on the fly from a single web app (Umbraco) in azure?

Tags: azure, hosting

I want to manage and maintain a single instance of Umbraco CMS locally and on the fly, when customers want a duplicate instance, be able to automatically create new instances of the application.

Ideally I'd like a process whereby it builds from the master branch, creates an azure app from the build and deploys it to a new Azure Web App, along with cloning a database on an existing Azure SQL Server. And if I have any updates that I want to push to all instances, I would like to build and deploy updates to all Azure Web Apps created so far.

It's basically a very vertical multi tenant application that requires new instances of it. There is no crossover other than they share the same code base and was cloned initially from the same database.

Are there any existing services that Azure provide for a single repo to multiple Azure Apps, and be able to continually deliver updates to all these clones?

Or is this more bespoke? I'm leaning to bespoke but I really want to check before reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What about using containers?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I was thinking about that. Though, orchestration of the container creation and maintenance is an issue. I imagine something like Kubernetes (container orchestration) is more for orchestration of a single application or services of a single application, or at least I am struggling to see how it can be used for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a bit like the concept of Baselines that Umbraco Cloud provides... https://umbraco.com/umbraco-cloud-pricing/#baseline

Comment: Wow. I didnt know cloud did that! Thank you very much :)